# How to add a delay to message.delete()?

Tags: python, discord, python-3.7, discord.py

If a command is given in any other channel besides the one designated, the bot deletes the command message and informs the user they can only use commands in the help channel. I'd like the bot to then delete it's own message after about 5 seconds.

This is what I have and am trying, the API documentation says to add a delay= in `await message.delete()` but when I do that, the message remains. Even without it says the message doesn't exist, it's an unknown message, and on one instance I nearly deleted the entire general channel.

Code:

```
if message.content.startswith('!commands'):
        channel = client.get_channel(525412770062139402)
        if message.channel is not channel:
            await message.delete()
            channel = message.channel
            await channel.send("{0.mention} Please use bot commands in the #help channel.".format(message.author))
            channel = message.channel
            await message.delete()
```

This tells me it's an unknown message. How would I retrieve the bot's last message? If I'm understanding this correctly, the bot's trying to retrieve the message already deleted, not it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TextChannel.send(...)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.send) returns a `Message` too, so if you want to store the message that your bot just sent, you can do:

```
botSentMessage = await channel.send("some message")
```

Then finally, to add delay, you can use [`await asyncio.sleep(delayInSeconds)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping).

Your end result should be this:

```
if message.content.startswith('!commands'):
        channel = client.get_channel(525412770062139402)
        if message.channel is not channel:
            await message.delete()
            channel = message.channel

            # Gets the message the bots just sent.
            botsMessage = await channel.send("{0.mention} Please use bot commands in the #help channel.".format(message.author))
            # Waits for 3 seconds before continuing to the next line of code
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            await botsMessage.delete()
```

Comment: I see what you did. Thank you, once again

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this :

```py
await ctx.send("My message", delete_after = 5)
```

The `delete_after` parameter will delete the sent message automatically at the end of the countdown. [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=delete_after#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)

Answer (score 0):

You can use time sleep function:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This is blocking, better use `asyncio.sleep()`